# .htaccess only redirects when target does not exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to use `.htaccess` to alias a url like `example.com/short` to `example.com/short.php` but when I test the configuration I only get redirected when I request a php script that doesn't exist. For example: the page `short.php` exists but `shor.php` does not yet when I request the page for `example.com/short` I get the 404 page for `example.com/short` but when I request `example.com/shor` I get the 404 page for `example.com/shor.php`

the `.htaccess` I am using is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^s/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ short.php?code=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that in your `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^s/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ short.php?code=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```